# Just audio flutter package streaming quality problem

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation, just-audio

I am developing mobile app in flutter where I want to change the streaming song quality like
96 Kbps,160 Kbps,320 Kbps

I don't know how to change the user-defined streaming songs quality

I am using `just_audio: ^0.9.24`

It would be great if someone gives a solution to this

While songs are streaming state or not at that time or any other time I want to change my streaming song's quality

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following to change the streaming song quality:

```
import 'package:just_audio/just_audio.dart';
void main(){
final player = AudioPlayer();
player.quality = AudioQuality.high;
player.play('https://sample.com/sample.mp3');
```

Comment: can you share your code part?

Comment: yeah sureee.....

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EMs6g.png

this is my coding part screenshot url

Comment: it's difficult to suggest solution by only seeing particular code part. But do remember `just_audio` package doesn't support changing the audio streaming quality. It provides `AudioQuality` enum for using local audio files only. If you want to change the quality of the streaming audio, then you need to modify `audio stream request` itself.